# Joining Array[Bytes] using Spark foreachPartition and ListBuffer

Tags: java, arrays, scala, apache-spark

My goal is to merge some files together.  I'm obtaining these files, processing them and then returning them as an Array[Byte].  This is then parallelised.

I've changed the variable names to make reading easier.

```
val files= sc.parallelize(listOfFilesToProcess)
  .map(m => processFilesAndReturnByteArray(fileLocation, fileName,))
```

I then take `files` and iterate over each partition in an attempt to merge the files together and create fewer larger files.  My initial attempt used strings and with that I had an `Iterator[Option[String]]` which was fine - I had a very simple loop that worked well but was terribly inneficient:

```
  files.foreachPartition(iter => {
        val txt = iter.mkstring
          saveFile(outputLocation, outputPath, txt.bytes)
        })
```

To try and improve the efficiency I'm now using Array[Bytes] meaning my Iterator is `Iterator[Option[Array[Byte]]]` - I'm quite new to Spark and Scala so the chances of making a daft mistake are high.

With the bytes I couldn't find a way to join them all together without going through the iterator process meaning that I was creating as many files as I had to start with, one for each so the app at this point was quite useless.  I then thought to use a ListBuffer to concat these byte arrays and then save it but that in itself is creating erroneous output including 0 byte files and files where the data is repeated.

It would be great if someone coudl take a peek and point me in the right direction, thanks!

This is the current version I'm using for the bytes:

```
  files.foreachPartition(iter => {
          val joinedBytes = new ListBuffer[Byte]
          while(iter.hasNext) {
            val item = iter.next()
            item match{
              case Some(x) => joinedBytes.++=(x)
              case None => Logger.info("Todo: Handle this properly")
            }
          }
          saveFile(outputLocation, outputPath, joinedBytes.toArray)
        })
```

Comment: This sounds more of a question for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - I have to disagree, I'm basically saying that I've tried to implement an algorithm and it's not working as expected so I'm asking the community for help.  If it was working perfectly and I wanted to refine it then yes, CodeReview would probably be a better place.  Unfortunatley it's not working, nor is it perfect. :D

Comment: This does not seem to fit Spark in any way.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh - would you care to elaborate on that?